# The header becomes the footer upon scrolling using FullPage.js

Tags: fullpage.js

I'm using fullPage.js for almost a month only and I'm still on the process of testing it.

Is it possible that upon scrolling from another section the header in section-1 becomes the footer in section-2?

Example is this.

From this section-1, notice the header part.
[image]

To this section-2, notice that the header from section-1 becomes the footer in section-2.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with something like this:

```
var windowsHeight = $(window).height();

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['yellow', 'orange', '#C0C0C0', '#ADD8E6'],
    onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){
        if(index == 1){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.header').css('top', '').css('bottom','').addClass('fixed');
            }, 650);
        }

        if(nextIndex == 1){
            $('.header').animate({
                top: windowsHeight - 100,
                bottom: '0'
            }, 700, 'easeInQuart', function(){
                $('.header').css({'top' : '', 'bottom' : ''});
                $('.header').removeClass('fixed');
            });     
        }
    },

    afterResize: function(){
        windowsHeight = $(window).height();
    }
});
```

Here's the [living demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/258/).

I haven't tried it with `css3:true`, you might have some problems there.

## Update:

For CSS3 true, which is the default option now, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992060/dynamically-making-an-element-fixed-header-in-fullpage-js/27994909#27994909).

Comment: This is really amazing @alvaro, I suggest adding example like that on your documentation. :) I really appreciate it. Thanks!