# How can I temporarily fix an element while scrolling page then have it scroll normally again?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, fullpage.js

[Here](http://beta.flashbrand.me/SITE/index.html) is what I am trying to do.

As you can see the transition is a bit shaky. How would you recreate this with a smooth transition/animation? 
I am using  a plugin (Fullpage.js) which disables traditional scrolling so anything using "offset" to change the element position to fixed would not work.

Comment: You may be able to use _position: fixed_ with it's _top_ and _left_ coördinates in the _CSS_ for the right section when it is supposed to remain stationary on the screen.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27992060/dynamically-making-an-element-fixed-header-in-fullpage-js